# How we can get the value from string: 1;BWQTY;4|2;NGRID;34664 and store into a variable if any specific SUBSTRING found?

Tags: oracle, plsql, substring, charindex

I have a table name as **event_creation_template** which having column as **TEXT** ,which contains value like below :

```
1;BWQTY;4|2;NGRID;34664
1;DTYPE;Amount|2;LOYAL;R
```

How we can get the value from string:

```
1;BWQTY;4|2;NGRID;34664
```

If string is having BWQTY then store 4 into variable again search for the NGRID ,if string contains NGRID , we need in 34664 into different variable.

using Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Why not show us what you tried already? Have you read [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

considering the string like 'BWQTY' will always lie between two non-aphanumeric  characters and the corresponding values like 4 lies between either non-alphanumeric character or appears at the end like in the two examples above you can use below code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PR_PREP
IS
  V_VAR1        VARCHAR2(100);
  V_-VAR2        VARCHAR2(100);
  V_SEARCH_VAL1 VARCHAR2(100) := 'BWQTY';
  V_SEARCH_VAL2 VARCHAR2(100) := 'NGRID';
  CURSOR C1
  IS
    SELECT TEXT FROM EVENT_CREATION_TEMPLATE;
BEGIN
   FOR REC IN C1
  LOOP 
IF INSTR(REC.TEXT,V_SEARCH_VAL1) > 0 THEN
  SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(REC.TEXT,INSTR(REC.TEXT,V_SEARCH_VAL1)+LENGTH(V_SEARCH_VAL1)+1), 1, REGEXP_INSTR( SUBSTR(REC.TEXT,INSTR(REC.TEXT,V_SEARCH_VAL1)+LENGTH(V_SEARCH_VAL1)+1), '[^0-9a-zA-Z]',1)-1), SUBSTR(REC.TEXT,INSTR(REC.TEXT,V_SEARCH_VAL1)+LENGTH(V_SEARCH_VAL1)+1))
  INTO V_VAR1
  FROM DUAL ;
END IF;
IF INSTR(REC.TEXT,V_SEARCH_VAL2) > 0 THEN
  SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(SUBSTR(REC.TEXT,INSTR(REC.TEXT,V_SEARCH_VAL2)+LENGTH(V_SEARCH_VAL2)+1), 1, REGEXP_INSTR( SUBSTR(REC.TEXT,INSTR(REC.TEXT,V_SEARCH_VAL2)+LENGTH(V_SEARCH_VAL2)+1), '[^0-9a-zA-Z]',1)-1), SUBSTR(REC.TEXT,INSTR(REC.TEXT,V_SEARCH_VAL2)+LENGTH(V_SEARCH_VAL2)+1))
  INTO V_VAR2
  FROM DUAL ;
END IF;
-- DO FURTHER WORK
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions
for BWQTY:

```
    select str, 
SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '([BWQTY]{5})([;])([0-9]+)'),
      INSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '([BWQTY]{5})([;])([0-9]+)'), ';') + 1 ,
      LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '([BWQTY]{5})([;])([0-9]+)')) - INSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '([BWQTY]{5})([;])([0-9]+)'), ';')) AS VALUE
from test
```

for NGRID:

```
select str, 
SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '([NGRID]{5})([;])([0-9]+)'),
      INSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '([NGRID]{5})([;])([0-9]+)'), ';') + 1 ,
      LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '([NGRID]{5})([;])([0-9]+)')) - INSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '([NGRID]{5})([;])([0-9]+)'), ';')) AS VALUE
from test
```

Where str is your input string...